# Running on main thread

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

When I present a view controller or perform a segue in swift should I call it in `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` or is that a problem. My problem is that should I run it in the background thread or the main thread. If I load data from the database should I also present the view in `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` or should I run it in the background thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call all the UI related transition, changes and updates on the main thread. But where should you use `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` ?

It is to be used when the call is made from a background thread. Example,if you are downloading data and parsing from an API, you usually do that in a background thread, once that is completed, maybe you want a UI transition or update, So that update will take place in the main thread, and since currently you are on background thread, you require `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` to make the changes on UI.

Answer (score 0):

All UI work should happen on the main thread, so unless you're on a background queue there is no reason to dispatch to the main queue. In the common case the segue is triggered from user interaction (e.g. a button press) which would already be on the main thread.

If loading the data for the view that is being presented takes a long time, then you can dispatch asynchronously to a background queue to load it and dispatch back to the main queue when the data has finished loading.

Since this is asynchronous, it will mean that the view will be without data from the time where it is presented to the time where the data has finished loading. This is something that you have to handle in your UI. Depending on your application, one example could be to displayed a loading indicator while the data is loading. Another could be to fetch or pass a minimal amount of data to display and load the larger amount of data asynchronously.